# How can I make an iframe security error occur in IE?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

A user of one of my websites is reporting an alarming-looking frame content error on a page that embeds Google Maps. I have played with the security settings in IE9, IE10 and IE11 but have only been able to either display the embed without issue or display nothing (blank space where iframe should be.) **What do I need to do in which version of IE to see this error?**

Here is the embed in question (need to redact specific map.)

```
        <iframe id="googlemap" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?t=m&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=1234.1234&amp;source=embed&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.996163,-96.855469&amp;spn=33.053774,56.25&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Here is a screenshot of the error the user is receiving.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Open a new browser window, and pull down the "Tools" menu.
2. Select "Internet Options".
3. Click the "Security" tab, select the "Internet" icon, and click the "Custom Level" button.

> [image]

4. Scroll down to the "Miscellaneous" section, find the "Launching programs and files in an Iframe" entry and select "Prompt".

> [image]

5. Close all open Dialogs by clicking the OK buttons.